# Why usually service can't be called in broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I been reading android doc which keep saying me that to avoid the log running process in broadcast receiver . They are saying the receive can handle operation for short while but i yet to figure out why this is so .

What will happen if they allow long running task in broadcast receiver?

Comment: BroadcastReceivers for listening system wide broadcast not for long running operations..if you run it then ANR may occur

Comment: @kalyanpvs if we put our code in worker then then i dont think so its ANR issue

Comment: thats not a good approch it will be killed.they clearly said its not available..check documnet in lifecycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 0):

In Android, GUI events, services and receivers run in the so called Main Thread. This thread is very important and you wont be able to run long tasks (more than a few seconds) there. If you try, you'll get an Application Not Responding error, and your app will crash.

If it were allowed, as it was for instance in the old Blackberry OS, then you could block the user interface while doing long tasks, and the app would appear to be frozen. Not only the GUI events would be affected, every other component (other services and receivers) would block until you are done.

And that's why you should run long tasks in background threads. The API already has built in classes for this case: AsyncTasks, IntentServices, Loaders. There are also libraries to ease bg processing, like Volley.